# ExcelBuilder.js make text wrap inside cells

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm using ExcelBuilder.js to generate an Excel file from json data. I'd like to make text wrap inside cells, is there the possibility to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it's an option for a style

```
var wrapped = stylesheet.createFormat({
 alignment: {wrapText: true}
});
```

https://github.com/stephenliberty/excel-builder.js/issues/27